# How to transform an Excel list into an array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a two column list of key-value pairs. For example:

```
71  Archaebacteria
71  Mendosicutes
71  Metabacteria
72  blue green algae
72  blue-green algae
72  Cyanochloronta
72  Cyanophyta
73  CFB group
73  Chloroflecales
73  Chloroflexaceae/Deinococcaceae group
73  Chloroflexus/Deinococcaceae group
73  Chloroflexus/Deinococcus group
73  Cytophaga-Flexibacter-Bacteroides group
73  Fibrobacter-Acidobacteria group
73  Flexistipes group
73  GNS bacteria
73  Green non-sulfur bacteria
73  true bacteria
```

I need to 'flatten' the two column list into an array where the `key` remains in column 1 and all `values` for the `key` are moved to new cells on the same row.

Some `keys` have 20 `values`. For that case, there would be 21 columns (1 for the key, 20 for the key's values).

I have studied this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283964/convert-excel-list-into-array-format) but have not been able to successfully modify it to produce the desired results.

**How to transform an Excel list into an array?**

*Notes*: a solution may leave a `value` in column 2 and 'copy' that value to the appropriate row in the array. Alternatively, a solution may 'move' the `value` to the proper position in the array, leaving a key with a NULL value. These "clean-up" conditions are OK as I'll sort/delete to remove detritus from the new array.

Either a formula or VBA solution is good.

Comment: Have you tried pivot tables? They do exactly what you need.

Comment: I did but failed (or did not do it properly). I also tried COPY/PASTE/TRANSFORM - which produces the correct result but must be done manually for each key. Would you point me to a pivot table example that I can appy and test?

Comment: Use a Dictionary, there are plenty of similar examples right here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below uses `Dictionary` to organize all unique keys (71, 72, 73) and their values from Column A:B.

Afterwards it pastes the values to Columns C:D.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestDict()

Dim Dic As Object
Dim C As Range, C2 As Range, lRow As Long
Dim Names As String, ID$, Key As Variant, KeyVal As Variant, IDVal As Variant

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheets("Sheet2") '<-- modify "Sheet2" with your sheet's name
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Cells
        If Not Dic.exists(CStr(C.Value)) Then
            ID = C.Value

            For Each C2 In .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Cells
                If C2.Value = ID Then
                    If Names = "" Then ' first key value
                        Names = C2.Offset(, 1).Value
                    Else  ' second and up key value
                        Names = Names & "," & C2.Offset(, 1).Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next C2
            Dic.Add ID, Names
        End If

        ID = Empty: Names = Empty
    Next C
End With

lRow = 1
With Sheets("Sheet2") ' <-- paste the organized dictionary key anv values the columns C:D
    For Each Key In Dic.Keys
        .Range("C" & lRow).Value = Key

        ' splitting values from "Merged" string Key to array
        KeyVal = Split(Dic(Key), ",")
        .Range("D" & lRow).Resize(1, UBound(KeyVal) + 1).Value = KeyVal
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next Key
End With

End Sub

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Thank you for the inline explanations.

Comment: @JayGray you're welcome :) You should take the time to learn how to use the `Dictionary`, it's a handy and powerful tool

Comment: Until now I knew nothing about `Dictionary`, so thank you again @Shai Rado

Comment: Thank you again @Shai Rado - this is a life saver.